# Show full post (not excerpt) for defined posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to have the possibility to define some posts in wordpress where the full post is shown and not an excerpt.

There are various solutions like:

- Use a hidden html to declare this and code into the theme to either use the_content or the_excerpt
- Hardcode into the theme (if postid == xx then the_content else the_excerpt)
- Use post meta data and add "if" into theme to check for them
- Create a plugin which adds the functionality automatically and also a checkbox "Always show full" into the post-editor.

The first one is easy but ugly, 2nd one should be doable with some googling but the 3rd one seems to be the most appealing to me but I have no idea how to achieve this.

Since usually in the template all i have is somewhere the_excerpt method from wordpress. I therefore should somehow inject some code there and check if the checkbox for the current post is set and then just use the_content instead. Is this possible at all or do I need to modify the theme anyway?

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Maybe at first: Is this doable as a plugin independent of a theme or do I need to modify the theme in any case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use custom fields, it's more flexible, so you don't need to hard code the page ids.

```
<?php
$show_full_content = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'show_full_content', true);

if ($show_full_content == 'yes') {
    the_content();
} else {
    the_excerpt();
}
?>
```

You might be interested in [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), it can make it more user friendly.

Comment: Thanks i'll have a look at it. But this then needs to be coded into the theme and cannot be done "in general" for all themes right?

Comment: Not in General tab correct. You choose the option on each post. It also can be like radio box, or drop down etc. if you use ACF.

Comment: Yes per post. By 'in general' I meant not related to a theme. With your solution this code needs to be added to the theme and can't be done with a plugin.

Comment: The code needs to be added into single.php or loop.php or content.php depends on your theme.