# Wordpress Twenty Seventeen - Show full post not excerpt

Tags: wordpress

I would like to make some changes on the post page. I do not want to show the excerpt I want to see the full post - including images and youtube videos for example.

In addition, I would like to disable the link to the post entry. Since I am using “scroll to page id” the navigation is not working anymore.

I tried the plugin Advanced Excerpt Options without success.

I also found this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/28632374](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28632374/2689362) but I do not know how I can adapt it to my Twenty Seventeen Theme.

Comment: Your post page was showing excepts? The Twenty Seventeen template is known for not having excerpts except under search results and Recent Posts. Was there a change to your template?

Answer (score 0):

To show full text on wordperss blog post

Path: template-parts/post/content

```
<?php
        /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
        the_content( sprintf(
            __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'twentyseventeen' ),
            get_the_title()
        ) );

        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before'      => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyseventeen' ),
            'after'       => '</div>',
            'link_before' => '<span class="page-number">',
            'link_after'  => '</span>',
        ) );
        ?>

**and replace with:**

<?php
$show_full_content = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'show_full_content', true);

if ($show_full_content == 'no') {
        the_excerpt();
} else {

 the_content();
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you. but it's not working for me.
I even changed it to this but it's still not working.
do i need to restart the server?

 <?php
  the_content();
 ?>

full code: https://pastebin.com/PDAf9uhr